Power query Calendar from Month or calendar from table
I'm going to reformulate my question (first all sorry and thank you for your support).
I've a table "Horas trabajadores" with date column called "Fecha" (I cannot add images yet so I type on this way) where I don´t have all the days of the month if not several days:
Fecha
01/03/2024
03/03/2024
05/03/2024
10/03/2024
31/03/2024

I'd like create a new table called "NumberFromTo" with a column "WholeMonth" that from the month of the column "Fecha" of the table "Horas Trabajadores" generates all the days of the month to "WholeMonth"so:
WholeMonth
01/03/2024
02/03/2024
03/03/2024
04/03/2024
05/03/2024
06/03/2024
07/03/2024
...one by one until the last day
31/03/2024

Hope that would be easier to understand.

"I cannot add images yet... "  That is a good thing. You should NOT post images of data/code/error messages, etc. It is much better to post this information as text which can be copy/pasted.

Excuse me, I wanted to add a little image of the table to make it clear, nor the code or whatever.

It is a little hard to figure out exactly what you want.
But to create a list of dates that includes every date in the month that includes myDate, you can use:
   monthDays = List.Dates(
                    myDate, 
                    Duration.Days(Date.EndOfMonth(myDate)- Date.StartOfMonth(myDate)) +1, 
                    #duration(1,0,0,0))

If myDate is in March 2024, this will generate a list of all the dates in March (MDY format here):

This can be converted into the column names for a table by using the Date.ToText function.
Edit:*Examining your most recent edit, where Fecha has a few dates in it in the same month, you can easily produce a table with all the dates merely by, as I wrote in my comment replacing myDate in the code above, with the single date #"Horas trabajadores"[Fecha]{0}.
So the code to produce that table could be:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="baseDates"]}[Content],
    #"Horas trabajadores" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Fecha", type date}}),
    #"Todo el mes" = Table.FromColumns ( 
        {List.Dates(
            #"Horas trabajadores"[Fecha]{0}, 
            Duration.Days(
                Date.EndOfMonth(#"Horas trabajadores"[Fecha]{0}) 
                - Date.StartOfMonth(#"Horas trabajadores"[Fecha]{0})) +1, 
            #duration(1,0,0,0))},
            type table[#"Todo el mes" = date])

in
    #"Todo el mes"

Which produces a Table:


Hi!
At table "Horas trabajadores" I've column "Fecha" where I dont´'ve all the days of the month.
I want a new table that:
1 - takes the month of the column "Fecha" of "Horas Trabajadores".
2- From the month of the column "Fecha" generate all month days.
monthDays = List.Dates(                     #"HORAS TRABAJADORES"[Fecha],                      Duration.Days(Date.EndOfMonth(#"HORAS TRABAJADORES"[Fecha])- Date.StartOfMonth(#"HORAS TRABAJADORES"[Fecha])) +1,                      #duration(1,0,0,0))
Error:
The Date value must contain the Date component.
Detalles:
[List]

@LuisMiguel I still don't know what you are trying to do, as you have not yet provided a proper example. However, your particular formula fails because #"HORAS TRABAJADORES"[Fecha] returns a List, and the functions List.Dates and Date.EndOfMonth and Date.StartOfMonth are looking for a Date. You cannot substitute a List of dates for a single date.

We've a table "Horas Trabajadores" with a column "Fecha" with several days of a unique month (01/03/2024, 05/03/2024..). Here we've the month "03".
I want to create a new table "NumberFromTo" that takes the month of "Horas Trabajadores" (in this case "03") and generate all the days of the month.
This is because I'm calling the column [Fecha] and I'm obtaining the error.
Do you know how can I do it?

@LuisMiguel Repeating what you previously wrote does not make it more clear. Edit your question to provide a sample table in markdown that can be copy/pasted.

@LuisMiguel You may be able to just call a single date from that column.

I've edited my post, thank for your support and sorry again!

Thank you so much! When you introduce {0} at  #"Horas trabajadores"[Fecha]{0}. Means a range?

@LuisMiguel #"Horas trabajadores"[Fecha] returns the entire column as a List. {0} returns the first entry in that List.

ok @Ron Ronsenfeld! Tnank you much! Appreciate!

this will give you an idea, try something like this :
let
  startDate = #date(2013, 1, 1),
  endDate = #date(2017, 10, 13),
  dur = #duration(1, 0, 0, 0),
  numberOfDays = Duration.Days(endDate - startDate),
  datesList = List.Dates(startDate, numberOfDays + 1, dur ),
  #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(datesList, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", type date}})
in 

#"Changed Type"

